# Bulk post type conversion

Tags: custom-post-types, bulk

I have been given a client's wordpress site to update & improve. Biggest problem - I need to take about 200+ posts of a specific category, 'reviews' and convert them all into a custom post type 'reviews'.

On top of this I need to move a few custom fields that have been attributed to these posts, so they remain intact once moved.

I expect I'll have to write a custom script that will change the mysql direct. But before I get my hands dirty- does anyone have any experience with doing this? Any tips/ gotchas/ scripts out there I can use?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not really moving anything just changing a simple field named `post_type` for each post so you don't have to worry about custom fields or anything else.

Simply get the post id's for the posts you need to change and change them and if you don't want to create a custom sql query for that you can even do that by WordPress:

```
//first get the post_ids as an array
/*the SQL way 
    global $wpdb;
    $querystr = "
        SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id)
        WHERE $wpdb->terms.name = 'CAGETORY_NAME'
        AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    ";

    $post_ids = $wpdb->get_results($querystr); 
*/
//
//
//
/* the WordPress Way */
        $post_ids = get_posts(array('post_per_page' => -1, 'cat' => category_id));
    //then update each post
        foreach($post_ids as $p){
            $po = array();
            $po = get_post($p->ID,'ARRAY_A');
            $po['post_type'] = "NEW_TYPE_NAME";
            wp_update_post($po);
        }
```

Comment: Brilliant. After posting this I started mucking about with the database and found it was a lot simpler than I thought it may be. Thanks Bainternet!

Answer (score 3):

You can just use this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/convert-post-types/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly through SQL as well (important if you have an enormous content library).  In doing so, you probably want to update the guid as well.  SQL for updating both post_type and guid:

```
UPDATE wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID=pm.post_id
SET
    p.post_type='NEW_POST_TYPE',
    p.guid=REPLACE(p.guid, 'OLD_POST_TYPE', 'NEW_POST_TYPE')
WHERE
    p.post_type='OLD_POST_TYPE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of making the change using SQL, which still works all these years later.  Thanks Bainternet for the tip on JOINs!

```
UPDATE ses_posts
LEFT JOIN ses_term_relationships ON(ses_posts.ID = ses_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN ses_term_taxonomy ON(ses_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = ses_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN ses_terms ON(ses_terms.term_id = ses_term_taxonomy.term_id)
SET ses_posts.post_type = 'recipes'
WHERE ses_terms.name = 'Recipes'
AND ses_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND ses_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND ses_posts.post_type = 'post'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention a better plugin available today that serves the same purpose (specially if this is one time requirement):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/