# Convert a category of posts to a custom post type using (MySQL) queries

Tags: sql

I am trying to convert over 2000 `posts` with a `category` of `hp_operator`, to a `custom post type`.

I usually use the "*Convert Post Types*" (a `plugin`) for tasks like this but with the amount of `posts` here it can't handle this in one task.

Maybe it is better to do it within the `database` with a `SQL query`? It should do some like following:

- Select all `post` with the `category term` `hp_op`
- Change/convert their `post type` to `hp_op` (a `custom post type`)

Comment: Check this [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12087/how-can-i-convert-posts-into-custom-type-posts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12087/how-can-i-convert-posts-into-custom-type-posts) for more info and answers

Comment: Took a look at the link, have already seen this answer but they suggest using 'convert post types' plugin for bulk converting but like I said this plugin just hangs when you try convert over 2000 posts.

'Post type switcher' plugin is useful for switching individual posts.

I am really looking for someone who knows their way around SQL queries who can help me select all posts from a specific category.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulk post type conversion](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26133/bulk-post-type-conversion)

Answer (score 2):

Look at this [Bulk post type conversion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26133/bulk-post-type-conversion), there are listed SQL/WP ways to do that. Try to do that yourself first with a db copy.

In phpMyAdmin there is a box to run queries, called "SQL". You can see a demo here http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/

Comment: I use navicat for my queries, will take a look at that link, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got really rusted with MySQL, but here is snipped that worked. It could have some mistakes as I said I got really rusted (e.g. make a backup first):

```
UPDATE  `wp_posts` p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy x ON x.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = x.term_id
    SET  p.post_type =  'new_post_type'
    WHERE p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND p.post_type = 'post'
    AND t.slug = 'customcat';
```

Here `new_post_type` should be `hp_op` and `customcat` should be `hp_op`. Although I think it would be more appropriate to use the build in functions in WP. Tested in on 10 posts and it worked - all posts with specific category were transferred as custom posts.

p.s. the category should be your category slug. I saw there is some digit after it's name.